# Problem with comparing character elements in C

Tags: c, strcmp

Am reading a file and storing the elements of this in a 2D array like this:

```
(file)                           
TLPINPUTS a b c 
AND e a b
NOT f c
AND d e f

(2D array)
xw[0][0]=TLPINPUTS
xw[0][1]=a
xw[0][2]=b
xw[0][3]=c
xw[0][4]=

xw[1][0]=AND
xw[1][1]=e
xw[1][2]=a
xw[1][3]=b

xw[2][0]=NOT
xw[2][1]=f
xw[2][2]=c

xw[3][0]=AND
xw[3][1]=d
xw[3][2]=e
xw[3][3]=f
```

i want to match the elements from the first line with the other like xw[0][2]=a , so a is in row 1 in xw[1][2] , i write some code it seems that is working fine but when it checks the b character of row 0 besides that he compares this character with xw[1][3] where is b there , strcmp crashes!
here is my code for this part can anyone help me ?

```
char *find;
   char *x,*y;
   int row=1,col=1,k=1;
   while(  row<lines && k<=ch1 ){
       x=(check[row][col]);
       if(strcmp(x,"NULL")==0){
            printf("change col\n");
            row++;
            col=1;
        }
       find=strdup(check[0][k]);
       printf("compare %s me %s , with row=%d kai col=%d\n",find,check[row][col],row,col);
       if(strcmp(find,x)==0){
           printf("FIND!\n");
           printf("(find)%s=%s(check) ,found in line:%d ,  type %s\n",find,check[row][col],row,elem[row].name);
           k++;
           //grammi=1;
           col=1;

       }else{
           printf("not valid\n");
           col++;
       }

   }
```

when i run this am getting this output which is not right it compares well the a character but b not :

```
compare a me e , with row=1 kai col=1
not valid
compare a me a , with row=1 kai col=2
FIND!
(find)a=a(check) ,found in line:1 ,  type AND
compare b me e , with row=1 kai col=1
not valid
compare b me a , with row=1 kai col=2
not valid
compare b me b, with row=1 kai col=3 
not valid
```

Comment: what is `check[row][col]`, I imagine that is of `char` , but this `x=(check[row][col]);` is not correct way of assigning, and read [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) about how to use

Comment: @IrAM check[row][col]  is xw array

Comment: @IrAM if this is not correct (x=(check[row][col]);) why it says find in comparing elements a and a from xw[0][1] and xw[1][2] and in character b crash ?

Comment: Use `printf("x=%s\n", x);` after  `x=(check[row][col]);` , mostly it crashes or it gives some junk after your `a` or `b` whatever etc.., `strcmp` is crashing because the comparison is entirely wrong, you should share the minimal reproducible example to be helped.

Comment: @IrAM x is printing the write characters every time when it read null because xw[1][4] is null , it dont change the row  (row++;) probably as you say my strcmp is wrong , i cant fix this but enyway thank you for your time !

Comment: Just a suggestion(use full for debug), when ever you read from a file, its good to print what you have read. better read about [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) and [strings](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/) you should be able to solve your problem.